# Spring 3 component scan project scope

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a web app that depends on multiple internal maven projects, can one wire components from other projects via component scan ? 
For example : 
in the application context xml of the web app project

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.app" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.projectX.service.impl"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.projectY.service.impl" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and that is how you do it. However, if there is an ambiguity, you might get into trouble. For example, there are several implementations of the same interface that you want to wire.